# Service-Based Database File Missing

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio, win-universal-app

### [image: Visual Studio Tutorial]

So I've been having problems with this tutorial for SQL on the MDSN website. The first picture says what it should like to add a new file to the project but when I try to repeat the instruction on VS the service based database file is missing. Does anybody know what I should do?

---

[image: My Results]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that you can't. Service Based Databases are for WinForms projects only and aren't available for Windows Universal Projects.

But you can use SQLite for UWP projects. The download is [here](https://www.sqlite.org/download.html)

Comment: Great, I did not know that u work with UWP. My bad, I didn't see the tag

Answer (score 1):

Please try to this way:

Go to Control Panel -> Uninstall a Program, select Visual Studio 201x, right click, Change -> Modify, and check whether you have installed "Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools", if you didn't install it, please check it and follow the steps to install it.

[image]

If you have installed it, to make sure whether it is related to your corrupted templates, please take the following steps to reset your templates:

1. Open Windows Explorer, and navigate to \Common7\IDE (by default is C:\Program Files or Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE);
2. Delete the ItemTemplatesCache, ProjectTemplatesCache folder;
3. Open Visual Studio Command Prompt under Start menu -> All Programs -> Microsoft Visual Studio -> Visual Studio Tools (run it with administrative privilege);
4. Run the devenv /InstallVSTemplates switch;
5. Run the devenv /Setup switch;

Hope this information is helpful.

Comment: I followed the instructions with no problem but I then went back in to VS and the templates were still the same. Should I try to reinstall VS or SQL tools?

Comment: Did you restart VS? Which version VS do u use?

Comment: What? Where did you see Visual Studio 2014?

Comment: I saw it in the "About" said it was V 14

Comment: Oh, 14 but no 2014 as you wrote before. It is different things https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio#History. Have U already tried to reinstall SQL tools?

Comment: I'm currently reinstalling VS entirely. I will see if this fixes it

Comment: And I was using VS 2015 but V14 I believe